# Автодополнение переменных, методов, классов

Tags: python, python-3.x, idle

В Python 3.x после первой установки работали все контекстные меню всех переменных, методов и т.д., т.е. кода была запись следующего вида:

s = ' '

код программы

s.   - (появлялось контекстное меню применительно к строковой переменной)

теперь этого нет, хотя по служебным все работает, например в type.

Пишу на IDLE 3.10.4

Comment: какой редактор кода вы используете?

Comment: Пишу на IDEL 3.10.4

Comment: Это называется автодополнение кода. Конекстное меню это несколько другое.

Comment: Если Вам необходим autocompleting кода, то PyCharm Вам в руки. Вы будете в восторге.

Comment: Да, установил PyCharm, потом установил модуль win32com, а он его не видит))